# How to play similar notes appeared simultaneously?

Tags: piano, sheet-music

[image]
[image]

Hi, before all, I searched but could not find a similar question, sorry if it is a repetitive question!
At the beginning of this piece of Music (the first few bars) composed by Yanni, in both pictures above, there are some Es, brought simultaneously (between the parentheses on the bass clef) on both staves in a grand staff. What does that mean and how to play the same note on both staves? Does that mean it is optional to play these notes either with right or left hand depending on the player, doesn't it?

PE: @Dom In this situation there's extra parentheses which are not included in the question you gave the link above, so I thought there might be a difference, though I think they are a bit different. Anyway, thanks for your note...

Comment: You have to play everything except the notes between parenthesis. This notation can be used to explain the melody that was meant, which can be useful to understand the music better and also for arranging where the overlapping notes might be played by separate instruments.

Comment: @Karlo Thanks, this part is a bit hard for me to understand (to explain the melody that was meant), but anyway thanks for this great explanation 

Comment: This is an example that illustrates what I meant -- Imagine that you are writing a four-part fugue, and at a given point, two voices play/sing the same note at the same time. On a piano reduction, one of these two notes can be written with parentheses because you cannot play a note with two fingers. In this case, the note is still written because otherwise the whole piece would consist of four notes at a time, except at this point where you would have three notes at a time.

Comment: It is a possible interpretation, I am not sure that that is the reason for the parentheses in your case.